# Accessibility turns off after app update?

Tags: android, updates, accessibilityservice

Accessibility Service is enbaled by user but on app update it gets disabled.
I am using different package name for the service but exported was set to false  in manifest so it shouldn't matter.How to fix this issue?

Comment: If you change the package, the user will have to re-enable your app, because the information the system had stored for your `Service` points to a class that doesn't exist anymore.

Comment: But if exported is false in manifest can't we change the package name..i referred https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/service-element.html ...android:name which specifies unless exported=false

Comment: When they say `exported="false"`, they mean to imply that the component is used only by your app internally. That doesn't apply here, since the system is handling the `AccessibilityService`.

Comment: Ok , thanks for clearing the concept.

Comment: No problem. Yeah, that statement about `exported` is kinda misleading, but I'm not sure that it's the Android engineers' fault. I think, technically, any component that has `exported="false"` is not supposed be accessible anywhere outside of the app, but, somehow, that doesn't seem to be the case for certain components, at least on certain builds. If it were the case, then you wouldn't even have this question, 'cause your `AccessibilityService` just wouldn't work at all now. Anyway, the main thing here is that your class's full name has changed, so the system doesn't know about it anymore.